# Inner product in Maschke's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am working through Maschke's Theorem on page 16 in Bruce Sagan's [*The Symmetric Group*](http://books.google.at/books?id=Jm-HBaMdt8sC&lpg=PA248&ots=9iXIZNgrhN&dq=bruce%20e.%20sagan.%20the%20symmetric%20group&hl=de&pg=PA248#v=onepage&q&f=false):

In order to prove the theorem the author constructs an inner product $\langle v, w \rangle' = \sum_{g \in G} \langle gv , gw \rangle$.

However, I fail to see why $\langle v, w \rangle'$ satisfies the definiteness property of the inner product. In other words, I do not know how to prove $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$.

The "if"-implication is obvious, but I cannot see why $v = 0$ if $\langle v, w \rangle' = 0$.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You have $\langle gv,gv\rangle \geqslant 0$ for all $g\in G$ and $v\in V$, with equality only for $v = 0$, since $G$ acts as a group of automorphisms of $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ \langle v, v \rangle' = \sum_{g \in G} \langle gv , gv \rangle = 0$ but each of the terms are non-negative so they must all be zero... $ \langle gv , gv \rangle = 0$ implies that $v = 0$.

Hmm... I wonder if you could say the average of a bunch of positive definite matrices is positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

As $g.V=V$ for all $g \in G$ (because this is an *action* of $G$ on $V$), and each of these is a linear map, we have that $g:V \rightarrow V$  is a linear isomorphism. So for all $g \in G$, $g.v=0$ if and only if $v=0$. So in order to show $\langle v,v \rangle'=0 \Rightarrow v=0$, observe that $\langle v, v \rangle' = \sum_{g \in G} \langle gv , gv \rangle = 0$ if and only if $v =0$ by the remark above and by positive-definiteness of $\langle .,.\rangle$.